# Getting default value when from Jquery library not user entered value

Tags: jquery, jstl

In my project we are using spring, JSTL, bootstrap and jquery.
In the backend in a spring controller I am assigning list of food values to key "foodList". In the UI I am iterating over it and displaying the value.

I made field "weight" as a text input. Default value will be printed what ever it is set from the backend. If a user wants to change he can do so.

When user changes value I want to get the modified value, but in the jquery code I am always getting the default value, not the one updated by user.

Could someone please help what is wrong in my code.

HTML code,

```
<table id="table_food"
    class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Food Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${foodList}" var="det">
            <tr class="clickable-row" id="${det.id}">
                <td><input type="text" class="inputWeight"
                    value="${det.weight}" id="abcd" /></td>
                <td><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                        title="${det.desc}" class="trunc">
                        <c:out value="${det.desc}" />
                    </div></td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".inputWeight").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val()); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no issue with your jQuery code.the reason behind not getting desired output is you actually bind you input value with a variable just do one thing put previos data in placeholder value and set value attribute blank